# Allow me to find a "community" by sort of a synonym or tag name

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When you click "StackExchange" drop down at the top and you search for the community.  It would be nice to find a community based on a tag / acronym name such as "UX" to find User Experience, "SO" to find Stack Overflow, "MSE" to find Meta Stack Exchange.

Currently when I type in UX, it shows Unix & Linux.  If I type MSE nothing comes up.

Comment: As for ux: it shows ux.se actually (the second item).

Comment: Right but thats because it begins with a U.

Comment: ... and you say that it shows only U&L :)

Comment: What I mean is it should work based on an acronym not just text.  How did I know someone would say that.

Answer (score 2):

Currently it seems to do a fulltext search in the web's address and official name, therefore for instance both `dey` and `dai` point to *Mi Yo**dey**a* a.k.a *Ju**dai**sm.SE*.

I don't see any harm in adding all common abbreviations to the fulltext, for instance:

- `MSE` for all of Math.SE, Meta.SE, Mathematica.SE
- <strike>`UX` for UX.SE and Unix.SE already works</strike>
- `MO` for MathOverflow
- `SX` for SpaceExploration.SE
- `SO` for StackOverflow
- etc.

Answer (score 1):

How would you resolve the ambiguities?

What's "MSE"? Meta Stack Exchange or Math Stack Exchange or Mathematica Stack Exchange?

What about "CS"? Is that Computer Science, Computational Science, or Cognitive Science?

"Web" is Webmasters or Web Applications?

Comment: You would bring all of them up..in the case they are the same...of course ordered by most widely used to you...so me considering I use meta stack exchange more than math stack exchange would show me meta stack exchange first followed by math stack exchange.

Comment: And you may add that I might not use any of these sites, in that case if the acronym matches more than 1 site then order it alphabetically.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a proper solution would at least be to search for the domain name as well as the community name.

For example, I was just trying to search for community issue is trying to find the one associated with Apple.  The domain name is apple.stackexchange.com however the name of the community is (unfortunately) "Ask Different".  I finally had to do some searches, find the community, and then get the name from there to add it to my "YOUR COMMUNITIES" list.

Thanks.